# How to setup MFA to other IAM user in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to setup MFA to other IAM users in AWS? Is there a way to do that? I only found that I could force them to authenticate themselves but is there a way for an administrator to setup MFA for other IAM users?

Comment: If then you will need to use your device and let them know the OTP code everytime when they need to access to aws. is this what you need?

Comment: What do you mean by "MFA to other IAM users"?

Comment: Consider an example where I can send a MFA authentication link to individual users and let them scan it with Google Authentication. Hope I was able to convey properly. For one of my clients, we got a link to mail to authenticate it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done from the console, but you must be aware that you will need a device to bind it to that the user if they are to be able to login.

To do it you will need to go to the IAM console:

- Go to the [IAM console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/home)
- Click the `Users` menu item.
- Click on a `User name` link
- Click the `Security credentials` tab
- Next to the `Assigned MFA device` label click `Manage`
- You can now sort out the MFA for the user

The administrator would need access to perform this action in IAM.

Just in case you are not aware you can also use the policy on the [AWS: Allows MFA-Authenticated IAM Users to Manage Their Own MFA Device on the My Security Credentials Page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_my-sec-creds-self-manage-mfa-only.html) page to prevent a user from doing anything whilst they do not have an MFA attached.

Comment: I was actually looking for something else where we can send a MFA authentication link which generates a QR code to scan directly from their mobile and enter coded through that link.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a feature of AWS and would be seen as a security risk. The users will require to be logged in when ever they add MFA, and will need to enter 2 consecutive codes.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so this is possible.
You can enable it for a user but the user needs to go through the steps to establish the MFA.
It defeats the purpose of MFA if a third person has access to it, therefore industry best practice is for a user him/herself to set it up.
MFA details in AWS document link below: https://aws.amazon.com/iam/features/mfa/